Expo go app wont open my react native app on phone
I setup a project in react native and expo (I am following tutorial)
I started the expo npx expo start -c everyting running in VS code, the QR code is there and also other stuff
I open the camera scan the code and got this -> "There was a problem loading the requested app. The request timed out. It looks like you may be using a LAN URL make sure your device is on the same network etc."
What I tried:
Uninstalled and reinstalled node_modules
Changed Node.js version to v20 using nvm
Renamed metro.config.js to metro.config.cjs
Updated Expo SDK version to match Expo Go app
Installed missing Expo dependencies
Configured babel settings
Cleaned Expo cache
Tried tunnel connection instead of LAN
Updated package.json configuration
Installed additional babel plugins
Fixed ECMAScript module settings
Cleared npm cache
Removed deprecated expo-cli
Switched to local Expo CLI
Used different connection methods in Expo Go
What I expected:
I was expecting to start working and I will see the app running on my phone.
Thanks a lot!

make sure your both device are on same wifi network

npx expo start --tunnel should work. The other options is to activate the usb debugging mode on your phone and connect to your pc using usb cable. check adb devices if you could find your phone there, you can start the app on the phone by pressing a in the terminal.
